# Highcharts funnel graph constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was following the method to construct a funnel graph as outlined here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/funnel/

However, I get a problem:

```
highstock.js:395 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Im making the chart via a constructor as follows:

```
<script>

new Highcharts.StockChart({"chart": {"type": "funnel", "renderTo": 
"currentUserBase"}, "series": [{"data": [["shadow", 3485], 
["requested_waitlist", 76], ["waitlisted", 469], ["invited", 68], ["waiting_for_account", 26], ["active", 428]], "name": "Value"}],
 "title": {"text": ""}, "legend": {"enabled": true}});

</script>
```

The chart just doesn't appear, and I dont understand why isnt it working. I've tried editing the original jsfiddle, and it can't work either.. Also, im using highstock because i need the time series graphs, and i read that highstock can be used for normal graphs as well.

Anyone got any idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, it was a stupid mistake, but instead of deleting the question I'll leave this here if it could possibly help others from preventing the same mistake.

Yes, Highstock can render normal highcharts. but instead of calling

```
new Highcharts.StockChart(...)
```

You call

```
new Highcharts.Chart(...)
```